# JSON.stringify add a carriage return

Tags: json, api, postman, response

I am using postman for batch API calls and want a new line between each records (for the ease of others copy and pasting into csv/excel)

```
let responses = pm.collectionVariables.get('collectionResponses')
if(responses) {
  responses = JSON.parse(responses);
} else {
  responses = []
}

responses.push(pm.response.json());
pm.collectionVariables.set('collectionResponses', JSON.stringify(responses));
```

I tried

```
JSON.stringify(responses, '},', '},\n')
```

and that did not work

This is what the output looks like
{"success":true,"data":"0.5950391865600001\t0.49508964727322147\t193.383783","id":"2ec0a50f-862e-11ec-a41f-06c185e97372"},
{"success":true,"data":"0.5950391865600001\t0.49508964727322147","id":"410113f9-8630-11ec-a41f-06c185e97372"},

Comment: you better show json you have and json you want

Comment: What are the array elements in `responses`? Strings? Numbers? Objects?

Comment: Either of you---did you one of you vote me down? Just curious the etiquette as java script is not my language and this may not be a friendly forum

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, most reliable way of doing this is to stringify each array element individually rather than all together:

```
const json = theArray.map(el => JSON.stringify(el)).join(",\n");
```

Live Example:

```js
const theArray = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2,},
    {id: 3},
];
const json = theArray.map(el => JSON.stringify(el)).join(",\n");
console.log(json);
```

I've left off the `[]` there because you seemed not to want them, but of course you could add them (`"[" + theArray.map(/*...*/) + "\n]").

Although `JSON.stringify` accepts a third parameter you can use for indentation (which triggers pretty-printing), it's awkard to use it for this purpose. You *could* provide a single space and then replace `"\n "` since a literal newline won't appear within a JSON value:

```js
const json = JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3], null, 1)
    .replace(/\n /g, "\n");
console.log(json);
```

...but it's a bit hacky.